# How to prove Y Y = Y (Y(Y))

Tags: lambda-calculus

I found a prove [online](http://goodmath.blogspot.com/2006/05/why-oh-why-y.html), but I can not fully understand it. The prove is like this:

- `let Y = lambda y . (lambda x . y (x x)) (lambda x . y (x x))`
- `Y Y`
- Expand the first Y:

  `(lambda y . (lambda x . y (x x)) (lambda x . y (x x))) Y`
- beta:

  `(lambda x . Y (x x)) (lambda x. Y (x x))`
- Alpha[x/z] the second lambda:

  `(lambda x . Y (x x)) (lambda z. Y (z z))`
- Beta:

  `Y ((lambda z. Y (z z)) (lambda z. Y (z z)))`
- Expand that Y in front and alpha[y/a][x/b]:

  `(lambda a . (lambda b . a (b b)) (lambda b . a (b b))) ((lambda z. Y (z z)) (lambda z. Y (z z)))`
- Beta:

  `(lambda b . ((lambda z. Y (z z)) (lambda z. Y (z z))) (b b)) (lambda b . ((lambda z. Y (z z)) (lambda z. Y (z z))) (b b))`
- `Y (Y (Y))`

What I do not understand is the last step. Since `Y` is

`lambda y . (lambda x . y (x x)) (lambda x . y (x x))`

why

`(lambda b . ((lambda z. Y (z z)) (lambda z. Y (z z))) (b b)) (lambda b . ((lambda z. Y (z z)) (lambda z. Y (z z))) (b b))`

is

`Y (Y (Y))`?

Comment: Is this clearer? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_combinator#Fixed_point_combinators_in_lambda_calculus

Answer (score 1):

Using the fixed-point property that $$Y f= f (Y f)$$ for all terms $f$, one can take $f=Y$ to obtain $$Y Y = Y (Y Y ).$$